# ffmpeg, создать gif, открывками

Tags: ffmpeg

Возможно одной командой выполнить данную задачу.
Видео длится 2 мин, то есть 120 сек. Из них необходимо составить gif, продолжительность одного цикла 2 сек. Необходимы первые 2 сек, затем с 30 по 33 и 3 цикл с 60 по 62.

То есть сгенерировать gif по 2 секунды, через каждые 3 сек. Но не более 3 раз, если видео короче 70 сек, в таком случаи не более 2 раз или скажем через каждые 20 сек.